# I got error this Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, integer given, called in

Tags: laravel

I am trying to update my record but unfortunately record is not updating i getting error please help me thanks.

Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, integer given, called in /home/zubair/htdocs/hourlog/cms/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php on line 869

https://flareapp.io/share/q5YBBDmX

**Controller**

```
public function issuesUpdate(Request $request,Project $project)
    {    
       
            $project_id =$project->id;
            
            foreach($request->date  as  $key =>$value){
            $issue               =  new Issue();
            $issue->date         =  $request->date[$key];
            $issue->issue        =  $request->issue[$key];
            $issue->project_id   =  $project_id ;
            $issue->save();
            }
          
        return redirect()->route('project');
    }
```

**html view**

```
@foreach($issues   as  $key=>$details)
                            <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-md-5">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                  <input required type="date" value="{{$details->date}}" name="date[{{$key}}][]" class="form-control"
                                         aria-describedby="emailHelp" >
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-md-5">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                  <input required type="text"  value="{{$details->issue}}"  name="issue[{{$key}}][]" class="form-control"
                                     aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="task...">
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-md-1 mt12">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger waves-effect 
                         waves-light btn-sm delete">
                                  <i
                                     class="fa fa-times">
                                  </i>
                                </button>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            @endforeach
```

**Route**

```
              Route::post('/projects/{project}/issues/update', 
        "ProjectController@issuesUpdate")->name('project.issues.update');
```

Comment: your function in controller is not updating data it is creating new data

Comment: are you sure your routing is reaching that function in controlller

Comment: I think `date[{{$key}}][]` should be `date[{{$key}}]` and `issue[{{$key}}]`

Comment: is it important to use 2 dimensional array in form as data all error is due to that 2 dimensional

Answer (score 1):

maybe this will help you try it

```
public function issuesUpdate(Request $request,Project $project)
    {    
       
            $project_id =$project->id;
            $dates = $request->get('date');
            
            foreach($dates  as  $key =>$value){
            $issue               =  new Issue();
            $issue->date         =  $request->get('date');
            $issue->issue        =  $request->get('issue');
            $issue->project_id   =  $project_id ;
            $issue->save();
            }
          
        return redirect()->route('project');
    }
```

Comment: i am facing same error https://flareapp.io/share/J7obbxP8